# php+jquery get values from serialized form with input name array

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm developing a PHP+jQuery application. I'm quite noob with PHP.

Anyway, I'm trying to send a serialized form to a PHP page that will store data to session, via jQuery.

This is a dynamic form, where I could have many input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
```

And this is an example of my serialized form:
name[]=name1&name[]=name2

I've tried to get the array with `$_POST["name"]` from the PHP page, but it did not work.

How can I get this array from the PHP page?

Comment: What do you see when you do `print_r($_POST["name"])`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something like this???

```
    $(function() {
        $('.submit').click(function() {              
            var names = $('input[name="name[]"]').map(function(){ 
                return this.value; 
            }).get();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,//this should link to your page
                data: {
                    'name[]': names,
                    // other data
                },
                success: function() {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```